# Counting all possible arrangements given a subset cannot appear consecutively inside a permutation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Given a square, triangle, and three balls {red, green, blue}. How many arrangements are possible where the three balls are not allowed to be next to each other?

That is no two balls (or three) are allowed next to each other.

The solution I have noted (textbook) says the answer is 12.

I know the complete set is $$s_0 = {t,s,r,g,b} $$

I know one subset is $$ s_1 = {t,s}  $$
I know the other subset is $$ s_2 = {r,g,b} $$

I believe this can be solved using a combonation of $$ { _{ n }{ P }_{ r } } $$
and  $$ { _{ n }{ C }_{ r } } $$

Two valid orderings would be `{r t g s b }`  or `{g t r s b }`

No matter how I try I cannot seem to put it together.

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Are you saying that no two balls can be next to each other or that the three balls can not be next to each other in a block?  That is, is $rgtbs$ a good ordering or not?

Comment: Correct. No two balls can be next to each other. A valid ordering would be `r t g s b `

Comment: So, then:  arrange the three balls ($3!=6$ ways to do that).  Then you have two gaps to fill (between the first and second balls and between the second and third).  There are $2!=2$ ways to do that, and the answer is then the product $3!\times 2!=12$.